# Calculated vs absolute engine load

Tags: obd-ii, engine-load, terminology

The [OBD-II protocol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_01) (SAE J1979) has a couple of PID's that relate to engine load:

```
+------+-----+---------------------------------+
| Mode | PID | Description                     |
+------+-----+---------------------------------+
|  01  |  04 | Calculated engine load value    |
+------+-----+---------------------------------+
|  01  |  43 | Absolute engine load value      |
+------+-----+---------------------------------+
```

I can see that calculated engine load is expected to be a number between 0 and 100%, while absolute load ranges between 0 and 25,700%.

Conceptually, what is the difference between these two fields?